# How to prove, on the client side, that my HTTP request has a specific source ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, networking, amazon-ec2, ip

## Background

I have an EC2 instance on AWS. The instance is in a private subnet which has the route table to connect to the Internet via a Nat Gateway. The Nat Gateway is associated with an ElasticIP, says `3.0.xxx.xxx`.

## Problem

I have registered with an API service provider. I want to be able to call their APIs from my EC2 instance mentioned above. The service provider needs that I send my IP address `3.0.xxx.xxx` to them and they will add my IP to their whitelist.

The registration is done but I have a problem about the IP Address. Currently the API return HTTP status 403 when I make a request using `curl` from my EC2 instance. The service provider's staff insists that my source ip is wrong, they cannot find a traffic with source ip `3.0.xxx.xxx` on their side.

But I have verified my Internet IP by running command `curl ifconfig.me` on my EC2 and see that the IP is correct as in the picture below.

[image]

## Question

Is it possible that the source IP of my request has changed to something else even though `curl ifconfig.me` returns `3.0.xxx.xxx`?

- If so, is there a way to check the IP from my side?
- If not, is the result from `curl ifconfig.me` a valid proof that my IP is correct? Is there another method that is undeniable?

Comment: Have you tried from an other non registered IP to contact the API. Do you get also 403, or doesn’t it answer at all?
IP filtering can be set at different level, and this may permit to identify that here this is not IP filtering the issue.

Comment: @Floh thank you for taking time checking my problem. When calling the API from unregistered IP, the API returns status 403 with a HTML response body having text message "Access is denied". So I think the IP validation is done on an application server.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS, you will have to check the nat gateway attached to your subnet, to know which elastic IP it is using.

I expect `curl ifconfig.me` to be working.

I would also check that there are not different NAT Gateways per different subnets in the VPC (frequent construct), since if you move your EC2 to another subnet, then the public IP seen would change.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have double checked in AWS console that I have only one ElasticIP and it is associated with the only one Nat Gateway. Actually, I have another AWS account that can call this API successfully. The network setup is the same. I don't know why the service provider's staff insist that my IP is wrong even though I showed them the screen shot having the result of `curl ifconfig.me` before calling the API.